# Alpha channel is white, not transparent, in Texture mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, workflow, image

I imported images-as-planes into Blender Cycle.  I clicked "use alpha" (premultiplied) and "emissions and transparent".  The images are fine in Render mode, but the transparent areas appear as opaque white in the viewport in texture mode.  I need the transparent areas to be transparent while I'm editing.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/27635#27635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cycles the transparency will not show on texture view. In Material view it will:

[image]

In blender render it is possible to display the transparency in texture mode or material mode:

[image]