# How can I make a partially transparent texture?

Tags: texturing, transparency

I want to make leaves with a texture on a plane, so that the leaves are colored and background transparent?

Comment: Use an alpha channel or enable "Alpha" under Image setting and "RGB to Color" in BI.

Comment: In case of cycles: use a mix shader, with transparent and texture as input

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/27635#27635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using cycles you can use a configuration like that..

```
image texture -> diffuse shader -> 
                                     mix shader ->  output 
             transparent shader ->

in the node material editor.
```