# My Alpha channel doesn't show

Tags: texturing, transparency

I tried to create a transparency but couldn't get it work.
What is that I did wrong? :)
The black background is still there and not getting transparent.
I also tried to invert the shaders in the mix shaders but then averything disappears, even the white and red surfaces.

[image]

Comment: Try duplicating the image node and setting it to Non-Color for the alpha channel. Also, if you could, it would be a lot more helpful to have a picture with the alpha channel going straight to the color node on an emission shader that goes to the surface input. Otherwise, it'd be nice to see a .blend. My guess is that the alpha channel isn't really changing across the texture.

Comment: I only add to "pycoder" comment: It look like there is no alpha channel in image. This also happen when you use "Image as Plane" addon and you don't check "use alpha" in import settings.

Comment: @Pycoder, Shubol, I tried these but still didnt get it right. 
I also added the files in the post.
My picture is a png but without an alpha channel in it, only black to be converted as alpha in blender, I tried with import as plane, check "use alpha" but what I need is that Blender interpret my black surfaces as transparent somehow.

Comment: @TomCG please pack the image that you are using into the blend file and upload the file again.

Comment: @TomCG please read this link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/27635#27635

Comment: @Cegaton, 
Thanks for the link, hadnt find it before, its a good one! :)
should I delete my post then? looks double I guess

Comment: Your image contains no alpha. Besides that you might want to consider adding the parking lines to the texture of the asphalt. Having a separate object for the lines will lead to Z-fighting, when two or more faces overlap.

Comment: @Cegaton, thanks for the tips and the link, it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alpha channel is mostly white. try to make it better or use this trick to use the black color as black alpha.
[image]