# Image Alpha Background Renders Black when using “Import Images as Planes” 2.0

Tags: import, transparency

This is a question about an old question which can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes). I also found an answer to that question by Cegaton, though the instruction in the answer didn't help me, and I suspect that it might have only worked for the older version. So I'm using Blender version 2.78, I enabled the "use alpha" and it still doesn't work in any view, I used Gimp2 for the alpha channel and exported it into png, and imported as a plane using the addon, the plane is still a picture with black opaque background.

Screenshots:

Picture in GIMP2
[image: The picture in GIMP2]

Exporting the picture as Png
[image: Exporting the picture as Png]

Importing the picture as a plane
[image: Importing the picture as a plane]

Choosing the picture
[image: Choosing the picture]

The plane in object-solid view
[image: The plane in object-solid view]

The plane in object-texture view
[image: The plane in object-texture view]

An Image for you to test on: [image: yo]
Please note I am not sure if the alpha channel will stay there if you download it please let me know down in the comments.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me on Blender 2.78, I'm not aware of any critical changes in that plugin for the last versions. Please indicate what exactly doesn't work for you as expected, preferably with screenshots. Show which interaction mode you use to preview alpha channel, import settings, node setup etc.

Comment: @MrZak Thank you for telling me how to improve my question, I will edit it shortly

Comment: @MrZak screenshots have been added

Comment: Can you please include a sample image that we can download to test.

Comment: When importing the image check the box that reads "**Use Alpha**"

Comment: As an alternative to checking the Use Alpha checkbox add Transparent shader and mix it with Diffuse shader using image alpha as factor (basically doing the same but manually). This is shown in the answer already linked in your question.

Comment: @cegaton the test image has been added

Comment: @cegaton wow you resolved my issue! you can post that as an answer!

Comment: @technikfe It was already noted on the original answer! https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP0Uc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case you did not enable

Use alpha:

[image]

In newer versions of blender that box might not be there but you can still select to have transparency as you import the image:

[image]

The trasnsparency will only show on Material or Render view, it will not be displayed in texture view.

[image]

For more details read the previous answer: 
[Image Alpha Background Renders Black when using "Import Images as Planes"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes)