# Imported PNG shows black instead of transparency in the background

Tags: transparency

Importing a 'smoke' image as a plane shows no transparency.
Still have black background.

[image]

What other settings should I tweak?

[image]

Comment: Did you try premultiplied alpha? Not sure if it would fix, just a thought. I can import images with alpha just fine in Blender Internal right out of the box, I think it works for Cycles for me too.

Comment: Does your image really have an alpha channel? What format is the image in?

Comment: Make sure that your image is in png format and not in jpg because jpg does not support alpha channel.  Make sure that the graphic application you used to create the image can generate the alpha channel because many graphical apps cannot do it correctly like in windows 10 or others..

Comment: @VRM I will try it again with premulti alpha. Have no idea how to use it though.

Comment: @cegaton I read and experimented with the answer from /27633/. The image is in png. Problem is can't find where is the alpha channel.

Comment: @Yves Bodson  It's a youtube tutorial download pic that uses a jpg but using png instead. At least I know  that alpha channel not detected or  not there.

Comment: The image you uploaded has no alpha channel https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdUWj.gif. Read section 2 on this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes

Answer (score 0):

The image you uploaded contains no alpha channel.

[image]

You can check the alpha channel for the image using the channel display switches at the bottom of the UV/Image editor window

[image]

**Blender will not magically create an alpha channel for you**, if the image contains none.

---

A half-ass solution (without getting into editing in an image editing app, or sourcing an image with a proper alpha channel), is to use the black and white representation of the image itself as a mask to control the mix between an emission and a transparent shader, so that the white pixels of the image will be emissive and the black ones transparent.

[image]

Comment: Issue solved with the illustrations provided. Simple set of nodes does the trick. The only thing missing was that in Render->Film the Transparent option needs to be ticked. Millions thanks