# Why does my transparent footage background have a black screen?

Tags: animation, shaders, animation-nodes, uv-image-editor, video

### PROBLEM

Hi, I'm using Blender 2.93. I have some video footage I exported with DaVinci Resolve. It has has an alpha channel. When I load it back into DV, it shows it truly has an alpha channel because I can put anything under it, and it acts as you'd expect: like a PNG with transparency in areas I want, but in video form.

Then when I load it into Blender as an image sequence: `Add -> Image -> Images As Planes`, and make sure the `Use alpha` and `Auto refresh` are both on... The video imports with a black background where it should be transparent, but the rest of the video is fine.

### WHAT I'VE TREID

- Everything I said above.
- The [images as planes docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html)
- This [thread with a similar problem,](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes) though with PNG's. Not working either.
- Exporting the alpha with *premultiply* and *straight*.
- [Ian Hubert's YouTube video.](https://youtu.be/RxD6H3ri8RI?t=27) And oddly, none of my video's icons are transparent as his are... Mine show black where they should be transparent, even though the transparency works in DV.
- This [youtube video](https://youtu.be/5rGCPKqMYmg?t=404) showing his footage having no black screen.
- Going to `Properties -> Render properties -> Film -> Transparent on`.
- In the `Shading` tab, the alpha output of the video is connected to the alpha of the Pirncipled BSDF.

I'm wondering if this is some video codec issue?? The video is a `.mov` file with a `DNxHR 444 12-bit` codec, which Blender might be incompatible with?

Any ideas?

Comment: What Ian use is an image sequence not a video ... I would say it is a codec issue I haven't seen  anyone to use video with alpha in blender. For any postpro image sequence in OpenEXR format is highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was a codec issue. In DV I exported with a GoPro CineForm codec RGB-16 bit, and it worked. I read the available codecs in the blender docs, and that one isn't even listed there, but I bet it's probably using one of the others listed, probably open source or something.

UPDATE 2022: if anyone comes across this problem too in Cycles, make sure you turn up the max bounces in `Render Properties -> Light Paths -> Max bounces -> Transparent`, or else you will still get a black background. Adjust `Total bounces` accordingly too, in the same area.