# Blender 3 - Add image to plane with alpha, cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, import, image

Having trouble with imported image on plane to use alpha.  I found this thread [Image Alpha Background Renders Black when using "Import Images as Planes"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes)
which discusses the problem I am having but it's not specific to 3.0 and it seems blender has changed a bit and it's not helping me resolve this.

Can anyone provide the basic/correct steps to add an image to a plane and use alpha in 3.0?  This must be easy and I must just be missing some key step.

My image definitely has an alpha mask. One thing to note, this is an image asset created in a different blender project if that matters.

Comment: Hi :). In material options set Blend Mode to Alpha Blend/Hashed. If you're using the *Images as Planes* addon, it should happen automatically ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper material settings are on this picture:

[image]